# Using -( archives -) gcc commands

Tags: c++, gcc

In compiling a DLL, I've been running into a lot of `undefined reference` errors, which I think may be caused by circular dependencies between libraries. To fix this, I've been trying to use the `-(` archives `-)` and `--start-group` archives `--end-group` options:

`gcc -Wall -shared Pipeline.cpp -I"C:/Python38/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Pleora Technologies Inc/eBUS SDK/Includes" -I "C:/Python38/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include" -L"C:\Users\fmkz78\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\libs" -L"C:/Program Files/Pleora Technologies Inc/eBUS SDK/Libraries" -o lib.dll -( -lEbInstallerLib64 -lEbTransportLayerLib64 -lEbUtilsLib64 -lPtConvertersLib64 -lPtUtilsLib64 -lPvAppUtils64 -lPvBase64 -lPvBuffer64 -lPvCameraBridge64 -lPvDevice64 -lPvDSSource64 -lPvGenICam64 -lPvGUI64_VC10 -lPvGUI64_VC11 -lPvGUI64_VC12 -lPvGUI64_VC14 -lPvPersistence64 -lPvSerial64 -lPvStream64 -lPvSystem64 -lPvTransmitter64 -lPvVirtualDevice64 -lSimpleImagingLib64 -lpython37 -)`

Doing this results in the error `gcc: error: unrecognized cpmmand line option '-('` and again for the closing option. I get the same problem using the start and end group options. I'm running on Windows 10 using the MinGW gcc compiler.

Am I using them in the wrong place, or is there a problem in my setup?

Comment: What version of GCC? Try using the verbose syntax `-Wl,--start-group  ...  -Wl,--end-group`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`--start-group` and `--end-group`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651895/4386278) (and the short forms, `-(` and `-)`) are [*linker* options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30915737/4386278).

You'll need `-Wl` to use them from the compiler driver `gcc`, so that it passes them through to the linker rather than trying to understand them itself (which it can't, because it doesn't have any such switches).

So:

```
-Wl,--start-group
-Wl,--end-group
-Wl,-(
-Wl,-)
```

are fine.

But these:

```
--start-group
--end-group
-(
-)
```

are not.

By the way, you probably want `g++`, not `gcc`, unless you're deliberately skipping the C++ standard library (and other relevant runtimes) from your build.